# Ordering the letters by its sequence using regular expression in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I was trying to match the ordered letters using regular expression in php/javascript.

I have a 4 letter word in which first 2 letters should be in order and the next two letters should be in order like `BCEF`. This I wanted to match using regular expression.

But the below regular expression is also matching the order `CBFE`

Please suggest what's missing in the below expression to match the letters order. Thank you.

`[A-H]{2}[D-M]{2}`

Comment: why the tag javascript?

Comment: How `ordering` is connected with `regexps`?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're asking here. Could you provide some sample input and the output you're trying to get for this input?

Comment: It seems he is talking about *matching ordered letters* rather than *ordering* @u_mulder

Comment: Yes revo. Thanks for clarifying. I need a regular expression to match the ordered letters.

Comment: Use code for this. It's not suitable for regex, I believe.

Comment: Should the letters in one of the two *groups* always be neighboring letters, or can it be `AHDM`?

Comment: @ClasG, yes there are two groups in the same word in which each group should match the order but not the complete word. and yes AHDM is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a regex but php code instead :

```
$s = "BCEF";

$arr = str_split($s);

if ($arr[0] <= $arr[1] && $arr[2] <= $arr[3]) {
     // Your string matched
}
```

Comment: This is good. Only I don't believe there's a need to split the string prior to the test. The string can be indexed like an array as is.

Comment: @ClasG You're right. It's a habit I had, reading somewhere that `$string[int]` is equivalent to `substr($string, int, 1)`, I (probably wrongly) thought it was more efficient to access a value in an array than making a `substr` on each read access on the string

Comment: I'm not sure, it may be what you mean, but there's no need to *substr*. This will work `$s = "BCEF"; if ($s[0] <= $s[1] && $s[2] <= $s[3]) { echo 'Your string matched!' , '<br />';}`

Comment: @ClasG nope, what I meant was that I (probably wrongly) thought that the notation `$s[0]` is syntactic sugar for `substr($s, 0, 1);` and so the efficiency "problem" I hinted

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using regex (but mainly to illustrate how *stupid* it is ;).

```
(?:A[B-H]|B[C-H]|B[C-H]|D[E-H]|E[FGH]|F[GH]|GH)(?:D[E-M]|E[F-M]|F[G-M]|G[H-M]|H[I-M]|I[J-M]|J[KLM]|LM)
```

It has two (non capturing) groups following one another - one for each letter pair.

They tests for all possible *start characters* (`A` to `G` for the first pair and `D` to `L` for the second) being followed by any of the allowed subsequent characters, using alternation.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/o3SSyd/1).